# Change ComboBox border button on ISMouseOver

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

Inside ConrtolTemplate.Triggers:

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gainsboro"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FF8D979E"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#999"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

In the first 2 triggers i try to change `ComboBox` border on `UIElement.IsMouseOver` so i try to set `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gray"/>` but it seems that `BorderBrush` is not recognized.

Comment: put the code for button also please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ControlTemplate` looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Border" ... />
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Name="ButtonBorder" ... />
    <Path Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" ... />
</Grid>
```

Then in order to change border color, `BorderBrush` property of `<Border Name="Border" ... >` has to change. Therefore you should set the triggers like so:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gainsboro"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gray"/>
    </Trigger>
```